# Prevent different users simultaneously entering a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a Google Sheet that many users are using and I have created a script that automatically deletes all the values once the file is opened, so that the user always starts with a clean interface.

It is dangerous of course, when somebody is filling out the sheet and another person goes in and triggers the reset code.

Is there a way to prevent that two users are entering and using a sheet at the same time?

Comment: Yes, using [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/).

Comment: I believe the Lock Service can be used to prevent multiple users from executing a block of app script code. I do not think that the Lock Service will prevent a user from being able to open a document.  If appropriate, your script could clone the spreadsheet and create a new document for each user.

Comment: You can use the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) to accept only the change made by the first user who log: Like you get the user mail that you store on a properties, and you put a validation function on a onEdit() trigger that accept a change only if it's from the current user, same for your cleaning function. Once the user finish, you erase the properties and a next user can come and do stuff.